# Find the k largest elements in order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection

What is the fastest way to find the k largest elements in an array in order (i.e. starting from the largest element to the kth largest element)?

Comment: Can you assume that the array has no duplicate elements?  Or do you have to account for this case?

Comment: We do have to account for this case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option would be the following:

1. Using a linear-time [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) like median-of-medians or introsort, find the kth largest element and rearrange the elements so that all elements from the kth element forward are greater than the kth element.
2. Sort all elements from the kth forward using a fast sorting algorithm like heapsort or quicksort.

Step (1) takes time O(n), and step (2) takes time O(k log k).  Overall, the algorithm runs in time O(n + k log k), which is very, very fast.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really good approach.  Perhaps you'll want to add a few words about the case where duplicates exist and in particular ties for kth largest.  (Not a game changer, but something to consider.)

Comment: @hardmath, actually it makes no difference at all to the algorithm.

Comment: @rici:  As step (1) is worded, you will not succeed if there are fewer than k-1 elements "greater than the kth element".  Nor does it precisely fix things if these words are replaced with "greater than or equal to the kth element".  Am I being picky?  Yes, but...

Comment: @hardmath- If duplicates are possible, then we can address this in O(n) expected time by throwing all the elements in a hash table and reading out the unique elements back into the array.  You can then use this same algorithm.

Comment: @hardmath: it certainly won't work if the array has fewer than k elements, if you want to be ultra-picky. Otherwise, I'd suggest that the difference between "find the k largest elements" is reasonable vernacular for "find k elements which are greater than or equal to all the remaining elements", particularly given the link to the precise algorithm.

Comment: @templatetypedef, I'd argue that there is a semantic difference between "find the k largest elements" and "find the k largest values".

Comment: Here's my suggested variant: Find the kth largest element X using linear-time selection.  Find all elements greater than X and sort them.  Pad this sorted list with copies of X to achieve length k.

Comment: @hardmath and templatetypedepth: quickselect, m-of-ms and introselect are all partitioning algorithms; when they terminate, the kth element is in position k, and the vector is partitioned so that on one side of it everything is at least as big and on the other side everything is no greater. So it's unnecessary to partition or select again; it's only necessary to sort. fwiw

Comment: @rici- I think the question is about the kth largest element when there are duplicates.  The kth element in the sequence needn't be the kth largest when, for example, there are many copies of the largest element.

Answer (score 1):

C++ also provides the partial_sort algorithm, which solves the problem of selecting the smallest k elements (sorted), with a time complexity of O(n log k). No algorithm is provided for selecting the greatest k elements since this should be done by inverting the ordering predicate.

For Perl, the module Sort::Key::Top, available from CPAN, provides a set of functions to select the top n elements from a list using several orderings and custom key extraction procedures. Furthermore, the Statistics::CaseResampling module provides a function to calculate quantiles using quickselect.

Python's standard library (since 2.4) includes heapq.nsmallest() and nlargest(), returning sorted lists, the former in O(n + k log n) time, the latter in O(n log k) time.

Answer (score 1):

Radix sort solution:

- Sort the array in descending order, using radix sort;
- Print first K elements.

Time complexity: O(N*L), where L = length of the largest element, can assume L = O(1).
Space used: O(N) for radix sort.

However, I think radix sort has costly overhead, making its linear time complexity less attractive.

Answer (score 1):

1) Build a Max Heap tree in O(n)
2) Use Extract Max k times to get k maximum elements from the Max Heap O(klogn)

Time complexity: O(n + klogn)

A C++ implementation using STL is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int arr[] = {4,3,7,12,23,1,8,5,9,2}; 

  //Lets extract 3 maximum elements
    int k = 3;  

    //First convert the array to a vector to use STL
    vector<int> vec;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        vec.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

  //Build heap in O(n)
  make_heap(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  //Extract max k times
  for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
      cout<<vec.front()<<" ";
      pop_heap(vec.begin(),vec.end());
      vec.pop_back();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@templatetypedef's solution is probably the fastest one, assuming you can modify or copy input.

Alternatively, you can use heap or BST (`set` in C++) to store k largest elements at given moment, then read array's elements one by one. While this is O(n lg k), it doesn't modify input and only uses O(k) additional memory. It also works on streams (when you don't know all the data from the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `O(N + k lg k)` complexity.

```
int[] kLargest_Dremio(int[] A, int k) {
  int[] result = new int[k];
  shouldGetIndex = true;
  int q = AreIndicesValid(0, A.Length - 1) ? RandomizedSelet(0, A.Length-1,
    A.Length-k+1) : -1;
  Array.Copy(A, q, result, 0, k);
  Array.Sort(result, (a, b) => { return a>b; });
  return result;
}
```

`AreIndicesValid` and `RandomizedSelet` are defined in [this github source file](https://github.com/atiq-cs/Problem-Solving/blob/master/demos/algo/OrderStat.cs).

Answer (score 0):

*There was a question on performance & restricted resources.*

Make a value class for the top 3 values. Use such an accumulator for reduction in a parallel stream. Limit the parallelism according to the context (memory, power).

```
class BronzeSilverGold {
    int[] values = new int[] {Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};

    // For reduction
    void add(int x) {
        ...
    }

     // For combining two results of two threads.
    void merge(BronzeSilverGold other) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The parallelism must be restricted in your constellation, hence specify an N_THREADS in:

```
try {
    ForkJoinPool threadPool = new ForkJoinPool(N_THREADS);
    threadPool.submit(() -> {
        BronzeSilverGold result = IntStream.of(...).parallel().collect(
            BronzeSilverGold::new,
            (bsg, n) -> BronzeSilverGold::add,
            (bsg1, bsg2) -> bsg1.merge(bsg2));
        ...
    });
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    prrtl();
}
```