# Approximate with sum of Fractions

Tags: algorithm, math, sum, fractions

Suppose the result of adding fractions a/b and c/d is (a + c)/(b + d). Similarly the result of adding 3 fractions a/b, c/d, e/f is (a + c + e)/(b + d + f), and so on. 
I have the following problem I could not solve.

Given an array A with n fractions a1/b1, a2/b2, ...., an/bn, a number k< n, and a fraction c/d. 
I need to test if it is possible to take exactly k indexes {i1,i2,...,ik} such a way the sum of A[i1]+A[i2]+...+A[ik] >= c/d.
If this is possible print the indexes.

For example:
If you have the fractions 1/4, 300/600, 400/400, k=2 and c/d = 400/400
Then the answer is NO.
On the other hand, if c/d =400/404 then the answer is 1 and 3 because 1/4+400/400 = 401/404 >= 400/404.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the restrictions on `p` and `q`?

Comment: @user3386109 0<=p<=10^6 and 1<=q<=10^6

Comment: Then it seems that all you need to do is find the [k largest fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450024/find-the-k-largest-elements-in-order) in the array. When comparing the fractions, you can convert to double (as you suggested). Or you can cross multiply. Fraction `a/b` is greater than `c/d` if `a*d > b*c`. You'll need 64-bit numbers to use the cross multiplication method.

Comment: @user3386109 And why it works? If you have equal fractions, Does it matter the order?   For examen 4/1, 2000/500, 800/200?

Comment: @user3386109  Yes, I think you need to do some more work. For example if k=2 and you have the following fractions 4/1,2/1, 100/50, then you sort 2/1,100/50, 4/1 but the 2 greatest fractions 100/50 and 4/1 sum (100+4)/(50+1) that is lower than (4+1)/(1+1)

Comment: You're right, taking the `k` largest fractions is not going to work. For example, if `k=2` and the fractions are 400/400, 300/600, and 1/4, then the answer is 400/400 + 1/4 = 401/404, even though 1/4 is a smaller fraction than 300/600.

Comment: Start by finding and removing the largest fraction in the array. That fraction is the initial answer. Then search the array for the fraction that gives the largest result when added to the current answer. Repeat until you have `k` fractions. Running time is O(n*k).

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, that would work, but the limits are 1<=k,n<=100000. So, in the worst case the order is O(n^2) so it does not fit in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if 0 <= a/b <= c/d, then (a + c)/(b + d) <= c/d. So, all you need to do is go through the whole array looking for the maximum fraction. This is a linear time operation as it avoids the bottleneck of sorting the whole array.

Here is the proof of the statement. Assume there exist 2 positive rational numbers a/b, c/d such that a/b <= c/d. Notice then, ad <= bc, which would mean that ad + cd <= bc + cd. This is equivalent to saying that (a + c)d <= c(b + d), which implies (a + c)/(b + d) <= c/d. Because of this, your subset sum (as you have defined it) is bounded by the maximum positive fraction in your array. So, all you need to do is find the maximum fraction in your array (call it maxP) and return max(maxP, 0), assuming an empty subset is allowed.

Comment: I do not understand your response if you have a/b + c/d then the sum is (a+c)/(b+d) not (a+b)/(c+d). Finally, you need to take k fractions not only one.

Comment: Well, so what I am saying is that k <= 1, always. For instance, if you have an array of only negative rational numbers, then k = 0. However, if there exist some positive rational numbers, then you will just pick the maximum of those positive rational numbers. The reasoning is given above.

Comment: I think you are misunderstood the question. You have an array A of n fractions, all of them are positive, so you need to take exactly K indexes such that the sum A[i1]+A[i2]+A[i3] +....+A[ik] (sum with the previous definition) is the maximum as posible. Yo can not take only one fraction.

Comment: You are correct! I have misunderstood. In any case, we can first sort the input array based on a comparator. If a/b = c/d, but a <= c, then a/b comes before c/d. Then take the first k elements. This algorithm will have a runtime complexity of O(nlg(n) + k).

Comment: That does not work. For example, if k=2 and you have the fractions 1/4, 300/600, 400/400 and then you take the first two or the last two the answer is incorrect, because the optimal solution is the first and third

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an variation on knapsack problem. Try to maximize the sum of k fractions ( take k items to maximize value ) and see if that exceeds c/d.

Also when calculating the value, use `(a+b)/(c+d)` and so on rather than summing up their individual values.