# Java performance : Java logic to find the 3 highest number from huge list

Tags: java, list, performance

This was the question I was asked in an interview for checking the performance knowledge.

Question - I have a list (Arraylist by default and if you wanna change the list then justify) of integers.
There are millions of entries with random int values. 
Values can repeat.

From this list I need to find 3 highest unique numbers in below cases.

1) when time is limited (time effective)
2) when memory is limited (memory effective)

I attempted the questions but couldn't get the effective solution.
My solution was to use stream API, 
then distinct() to get unique numbers
Sort() to sort the list
And then display top 3 after collecting.

However, they said you don't need to sort. 
I thought of using 3 variables to hold top 3 values. 
Then I iterate over the list and check if current values in top 3 have higher values or not? If not then I swap.

However here, there are many comparisons and thus at every iteration we have to do these comparisons.

Can anyone suggest me what are some better ways to solve this problem?

Also, I'll be very thankful if anyone can provide some link /description /approaches for such performances related solving.

Edit : output required is top 3 unique values

Comment: Do you want to find the top 3 _unique_ values, or just the top 3 values overall regardless of duplicates?

Comment: Thanks @Tim for drawings the attention. I need top 3 unique values.

Comment: Define a collection of size 3. For each element in the list, if the element is greater than the smallest element in your new collection, replace it. This is O(n) which is the best you can do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768212/984823

Comment: This is more related to performance issue. I have few solutions to get the output myself. However the purpose was to get better solutions performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

The following method will return the `n` largest elements of the given `list`. We iterate over the list and add the elements to a `TreeSet` which stores its elements in sorted order (with O(log n) insertion). When the number of elements in the set exceeds `n`, the first element (i.e. the smallest is removed). Additionally, the set does not allow duplicate entries.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> highest(List<T> list, int n) {
    final TreeSet<T> set = new TreeSet<T>();

    for (final T t : list) {
        set.add(t);

        if (set.size() > n)
            set.pollFirst();

    }

    return new ArrayList<T>(set);
}
```

Example (for the list [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        list.add(i);
    System.out.println(highest(list, 3));
}
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: The pollFirst method remove the item from the set, so you don't need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any space limitations, then one option might be to add your list collection to a Java `TreeSet`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
// populate the above list
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
set = (TreeSet<Integer>)set.descendingSet();
```

Each entry in your list will be placed into a red black tree behind `TreeSet`, and duplicates will be automatically removed.  I make a call to `TreeSet#descendingSet` above, to give us a sorted set which will iterate in descending order by default.

Now all that is needed is to iterate the first three entries:

```
int count = 0;
Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext() && count < 3) {
    System.out.println("Value #" + count + " = " + iterator.next());
    ++count;
}
```

As for the memory limited approach, you would likely have to resort to some sort of in place sorting algorithm, which uses either only the original data structure, or perhaps just a bit extra.  I have little expertise with such solutions, so I won't attempt anything other than what I just mentioned.

Comment: And what about a memory limted approach?

Comment: @Glains I have never attempted anything like that, so unfortunately I can't answer.

Comment: Working and tested code, downvoted twice, with zero explanation given.

Comment: I upvoted, and have to say that's some nice code using `descendingSet()`. I am always amazed when I learn something new from `TreeMap` or `TreeSet` (like today with your answer). +1

Comment: @Lino It happened because of the dupe mark, hence to punish anyone stupid enough to attempt an answer. Thing is, when everyone here answered, the question was not duped, nor downvoted.

Comment: @Tim that's just how SO evolved, quite harsh culture with limited acceptance of duplicate questions / answers

Comment: @Tim: My comment didn't save. I downvoted because this is sorting the entire collection, which OP proposed and was shot down. While the code is simple and elegant, it is not efficient because there is much needless sorting.

Comment: @jalynn2 Not the same thing.  The OP is sorting using streams, while `TreeSet` uses an efficient red black tree as the implementation.  My suggestion would probably be more performant than the OP's sorting approach.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes more efficient than a simple sort, but building out the entire tree is still consuming cycles. I would make a variant of this approach by limiting the TreeSet to the three largest integers found so far, and only adding to it when a larger one is found and then removing the smallest to keep the tree size at 3. Then all integers found that don't qualify for the top 3 are skipped with a simple comparison rather than allocating resources and placing them into the tree in a place that doesn't matter to the solution.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did not downvote, i upvoted your answer and suggested an improvement.